# why do read some raster data and write it into a new tiff cost so much time?

Tags: python, raster, tiff, gdal

So here is my question, I have some raster data, and I have been using python and GDAL to read these raster data and merge them into one tiff, then I met some really annoying issue, First I tried to get one band of each raster and merge it into one single band tiff, it worked fine and fast, cost me about 5 seconds, Then I thought, why not make a loop,so I can get every single band in each raster and merge them into a multi-band tiff,but time it cost is way beyond my imagination, get three bands in each raster and merge them into a single 3-bands raster cost about two minutes, I mean, normally, if merge a single band tiff cost 5 seconds, wouldn't it be normal to cost 15 seconds to merge a 3-band tiff? I hope someone could answer my question, really confuse me, thanks, and here is part of my code,

```
import os, time, gdal, numpy, glob,
start = time.time()
os.chdir(r'...\...\..')
a = glob.glob(r'*.tif')

#a function to get the layer extent of each raster
def get_extent(fn):
    ds = gdal.Open(fn)
    rows = ds.RasterYSize
    cols = ds.RasterXSize
    gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()
    minx = gt[0]
    maxy = gt[3]
    maxx = gt[0] + gt[1] * rows
    miny = gt[3] + gt[5] * cols
    return (minx, maxy, maxx, miny)

#randmly get one raster's extent for later compare using
minX, maxY, maxX, minY = get_extent(a[0])

#comnpare all these raster's extent and compare their extent to get the output tiff's extent
for fn in a[1:]:
    minx, maxy, maxx, miny = get_extent(fn)
    minX = min(minX, minx)
    maxY = max(maxY, maxy)
    maxX = max(maxX, maxx)
    minY = min(minY, miny)
# some settings for ouput tiff
in_ds = gdal.Open(a[0])
gt = in_ds.GetGeoTransform()
rows = int((maxX - minX)/abs(gt[5]))
cols = int((maxY - minY)/gt[1])
driver = in_ds.GetDriver()
out_ds = driver.Create(r'...\mosaic.tif', cols, rows, 3, 
in_ds.GetRasterBand(1).DataType)
out_ds.SetProjection(in_ds.GetProjection())
gt = list(in_ds.GetGeoTransform())
gt[0], gt[3] = minX, maxY
out_ds.SetGeoTransform(gt)
#a loop to get 1 to 3 bands in output tiff and write the data into these bands
for i in range(1,4):
    out_band = out_ds.GetRasterBand(i)
    for fn in a:
        in_ds = gdal.Open(fn)
        trans = gdal.Transformer(in_ds, out_ds, [])
        success, xyz = trans.TransformPoint(False, 0, 0)
        x, y, z = map(int, xyz)
        data = in_ds.GetRasterBand(i).ReadAsArray()
        out_band.WriteArray(data, x, y)
out_ds.FlushCache()
out_ds = None
in_ds = None
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can divide your loop into 3 and add a timer. Basically, delete the for loop and divide it into 3 parts for each band then implement them to see the time difference between implementations. This will show you which band cost how much time. I think the answer is the contents of bands. The usage of one band probably cost much or less time than others. I suggest you, divide your loop and see how many time each band cost. Then look what's inside that band.

Comment: I will try to do it with your advice and see how it ends, but I still think using for loop is more simplify and automatic, right? I mean what if I need to get dozens of bands, the code will be super redundancy

Comment: Yes you are right loop is easier. Dividing is just for test purposes. I hope it will solve your question.